# Consume updated messages from an API(Streaming)

Tags: java, web-services

I have  to Consume  a Rest API in java, I am using HttpsURLConnection to connect to API and I am able to consume all messages from API successfully.

The problem is I have to hit this API continuously and have to consume only updated messages but every time it is getting hit and give all messages from starting.

I am using this below  code for connection.

```
URL url = new URL("https://aabc/xyz")
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.